# How to upload file using Gradle task properly?

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

I'm trying to upload a debug apk file to the server by Gradle. I'm using a special name for it, smth like "demo-testing.apk" or "demo-first.apk".

```
class Apk extends DefaultTask {
    String apkName

    @TaskAction
    void uploadApk() {
        exec {
            commandLine(
                    "cmd",
                    "-c",
                    "curl -F \"demo${apkName}.apk=" +
                            "@${DEFAULT_BUILD_DIR_NAME}/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk\" " +
                                    "https://URL"
            )
        }
    }
}

tasks.register("first", Apk) {
    group = 'apkUploads'
    description = 'Uploads first apk'
    apkName = '-first'
}
```

But it doesn't execute(with proper URL in the command line arguments) due to this exception:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject$CustomMessageMissingMethodException: Could not find method exec() for arguments [Apk$_uploadApk_closure1@58ed1
b0a] on task ':first' of type Apk.
```

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: the error message is quite clear: there is no such method `exec` on `Task` class: you should just invoke `exec` from `Project` class ( see https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project:exec(groovy.lang.Closure) ) =>  `project.exec` instead of `exec`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So thanks to the comment above I should have invoke `project.exec` instead of `exec` and it worked